# Error 500 returned from ORDS when creating a procedure that uses APEX_JSON within APEX's SQL Commands

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

The test case is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST IS
BEGIN
    APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT();
    APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT();
END;
```

I get a 500 error from ORDS running it from APEX's SQL Commands or SQL Scripts. I'm not sure if there's something else needed here or the recommendation is simply **do not use APEX_JSON in procedures**. I hope someone can chime in.

**Just to clarify**: I'm running this on an Oracle Cloud ATP instance, this seems to work fine in on-premise instances but not here.

### EDIT 1

I had already tried something similar to Ergi Nushi's answer but to no avail. I even thought my code was wrong and tried his instead but it didn't work either (See screenshot below)

[image: Error 500 using APEX_JSON in a PROCEDURE or FUNCTION]

### EDIT 2

So far what I have done to get my project going is to use the 12c JSON APIs instead like in:

```sql
-- ...
   L_JSON := JSON_OBJECT(
       KEY 'test' VALUE L_TEST_VALUE
       NULL ON NULL
       RETURNING VARCHAR2(32767)
   );
-- ...
```

I know this is not the answer I was looking for but hopefully, it helps someone to get going.

Comment: APEX_JSON is fine to use with ORDS. You do not need to switch to CLOB output. Could you please show us the other settings for the service and the URL you're using (from /ords/ on)? Also, have you checked the ORDS error log?

Comment: Hi Dan, I'm running on an ATP env so I've no access to those configurations

Comment: How did you create the service?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to initialize your `APEX_JSON` with:

```
APEX_JSON.initialize_clob_output();
```

After building your object you should get output with

```
APEX_JSON.get_clob_output();
```

and then free output in order to use it for other objects:

```
APEX_JSON.free_output();
```

Full code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST IS
    output CLOB;
BEGIN
    APEX_JSON.initialize_clob_output();
        APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT();
        APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT();
    output := APEX_JSON.get_clob_output(); --> pass the output to a variable
    APEX_JSON.free_output();
END;
```

Comment: I also tried that already but it doesn't seem to work either. Thanks for the help. I edited the question with the output from your code

Comment: Im not sure of your configurations. Maybe there might be a problem with APEX's version.

Comment: I'm running on an ATP environment, APEX 19.1, perhaps their ORDS configurations or something over there is the culprit